# h2 does not enforce NOT NULL in MySQL compatibility mode

Tags: h2

In MySQL compatibility mode, the following SQL succeeds and returns 0:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (i INTEGER NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (NULL);
SELECT * FROM test2;
```

It fails as expected in the default mode.  It also fails with MySQL 5.5 / InnoDB.  Does "MySQL compatibility" actually mean "MyISAM compatibility"?

Comment: MySQL will happily insert `0` if you use `INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (NULL), (NULL);` - at least in the default sql_mode. I think I also saw it insert `0` with a single value insert, but I can't recall the exact circumstances.

Answer (score 10):

This problem is due to both the way `MySQL` handles Null values and `h2`. Basically `MySQL` converts nulls received to `empty string/0` where as in `h2` there is clear distinction among all three types.

So, they(`h2`) have decided to convert the nulls to 0/empty string/current time stamp in `MYSQL` mode. But since the as per core h2 0/empty string are not nulls, so it inserts the data.

Use org.h2.engine.Mode and modify the variable related to this:

```
Mode mode = Mode.getInstance("MYSQL");
mode.convertInsertNullToZero = false;
```

This has worked for me. Thanks to [this](https://portal.permeance.com.au/web/terry.mueller/home1/-/blogs/solution-for-h2-not-failing-when-inserting-null-into-not-null-column-in-mysql-compatibility-mode) link.

Comment: do you know how to do this in spring/maven xml? I cant find any doc that shows that :\

Answer (score 4):

From [H2: MySQL Compatibility Mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility):

> *When inserting data, if a column is defined to be NOT NULL and NULL is inserted, then a 0 (or empty string, or the current timestamp for timestamp columns) value is used.* Usually, this operation is not allowed and an exception is thrown.

The MySQL manual says the following about [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html), with no distinction between MyISAM or InnoDB:

> Inserting NULL into a column that has been declared NOT NULL. For multiple-row INSERT statements [..], the column is set to the implicit default value for the column data type. [..] (*For a single-row INSERT, no warning occurs when NULL is inserted into a NOT NULL column. Instead, the statement fails with an error.*)

Thus I'm not sure why, or from whence, this choice was made by H2.

Comment: Oops.  I guess I looked everywhere except the H2 docs.  :-)  I love how the MySQL behavior changes, depending on how many rows you insert.  I think my best bet is to use the default mode in the future.  Thanks for your help!